# Gvim prevent accidental commands

Tags: vim

I have following code in my `.gvimrc` to prevent me from saving a file with the name `1` when I accidentally hit `:w1` instead of `:w!`

```
autocmd BufWritePre [1]* throw 'Forbidden file name: ' . expand('<afile>')
```

Is there a way I can do a similar thing for preventing accidentally entering `:e1` (to refresh a buffer) ? I couldn't find a `BufNewFilePre`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`BufNew`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#BufNew) should work:

> Just after creating a new buffer.  Also used just after a buffer has been renamed.  When the buffer is added to the buffer list BufAdd will be triggered too.

```
autocmd BufNew [1]* throw 'Forbidden file name: ' . expand('<afile>')
```

This gives me an error and leaves the current buffer intact when I do `:e1`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just auto-correct your fat-fingered commands? Based on http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Replace_a_builtin_command_using_cabbrev:

```
" command to define abbreviation that only affects first typed word in the
" command line
command! -nargs=+ CommandCabbr call CommandCabbr(<f-args>)

" helper function to create command-line abbreviations
function! CommandCabbr(abbreviation, expansion)
  if exists('*getcmdpos')
    if exists('*getcmdtype')
      " only expand when on COMMAND line and at first position
      execute "cabbrev ".a:abbreviation.
            \' <c-r>=getcmdpos() == 1 && getcmdtype() == ":" ? "'.
            \escape(a:expansion,'"\').'" : "'.
            \escape(a:abbreviation,'"\').'"<CR>'
    else
      " can't test command line, but only expand at first position
      execute "cabbrev ".a:abbreviation.
            \' <c-r>=getcmdpos() == 1 ? "'.
            \escape(a:expansion,'"\').'" : "'.
            \escape(a:abbreviation,'"\').'"<CR>'
    endif
  else
    " fall back to always expanding :-(
    execute "cabbrev ".a:abbreviation." ".a:expansion
  endif
endfunction

CommandCabbr w1     w!
CommandCabbr w!@    w!
CommandCabbr w@!    w!
CommandCabbr w!~    w!
CommandCabbr w~!    w!
CommandCabbr w@     w!
CommandCabbr w~     w!
" etc.
```